# Set HTML attribute value using java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I have html drop down list,which has country list. Now I want to set current country as a default value of list. I found the JavaScript code for get country using Geolocation.

My code:

```
function getCountry(var name) {
    if(name==geoip_country_name()) {
        return "selected";
    }
}
```

Then I need to set the `selected` attribute of the option list.

I tried this:

```
<option value="Sri Lanka" selected="getCountry('sri Lanka')">Sri Lanka</option>
```

But this is not correct.
Basically I want to set selected attribute value using JavaScript function

How do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean Jonathan?

Comment: @JonathandeM. Why would the OP need to listen for a change event if they only want to set the default value (once)? Also, they aren't using jQuery here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `window.onload` event, and just set the dropdown's value. Keep in mind that your hard coded country names may differ from the geo service.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("country").value = geoip_country_name();
    }
</script>

<select id="country" name="country">
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery following line should solve your problem:

```
$('select').val(geoip_country_name());
```

If `geoip_country_name` returns names in lower case, While initializing the select list, value for each option be in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do it like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <select id="country">
  <option id="germany" value="Germany">DE</option>
  <option id="uk" value="UK">UK</option>
  <option id="usa" value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
<script>
  var selectedCountry =  'uk'; //getCountry
  var index = document.getElementById(selectedCountry).index;
  document.getElementById("country").selectedIndex=index;
</script>
```

Start the script after your select is rendered.

Note, that this example might not be best practice. I'm also not sure if it works in all browsers (Opera works). You might use an appropriate framework like JQuery, Mootools, ...

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` attribute is not automatically evaluated as JS code. Assuming you have stored the desired country name in the variable `country`, could try this instead:

```
var country = "Sri Lanka";
var select = document.getElementById('myselect'); //Change to the ID of your select element
for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){
    if(select.options[i].value == country)
        select.selectedIndex = i;
}
```